# get value of field of table in android on press of button

Tags: android, json, button, tablelayout

I am creating an application where there is table whose data is obtain from server using JSON and is populated on screen. Also i have added a button in the beginning of the table and when the user presses the button, the value of first row and first column should store inside a variable.

i am not storing value in any database, just fetching the value from the server and then displaying it on the screen.

In the screenshot you can see buttons and the table. As soon users presses first button("Add to basket"), **it should store the value of product_code of that row only**(Only product_code) in to a string variable.

Please suggest me some ways by which i can do that. I am not able to get any answer.

sorry for my bad english

[image: here is the screenshot]

here is my code

```
public class FancyStock extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView label;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fancystock);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

        final GetDatafromDB_fancystock getdb = new GetDatafromDB_fancystock();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Users_fancystock> users = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ArrayList<Users_fancystock> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<Users_fancystock> users = new ArrayList<Users_fancystock>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Users_fancystock user = new Users_fancystock();
                user.setId(json_data.getInt("id"));
                user.setProduct_code(json_data.getString("product_code"));
                user.setShapes(json_data.getString("shaps"));
                user.setPair(json_data.getString("pair"));
                user.setCarats(json_data.getString("carats"));
                user.setColor(json_data.getString("color"));
                user.setClarity(json_data.getString("clarity"));
                user.setService(json_data.getString("service"));
                user.setPolish(json_data.getString("polish"));
                user.setSymetric(json_data.getString("symetric"));
                user.setTables(json_data.getString("tables"));
                user.setMeasurements(json_data.getString("measurments"));
                user.setFlourscne(json_data.getString("flourscne"));
                user.setDescription(json_data.getString("description"));
                user.setCerticated(json_data.getString("certificated"));
                user.setCcode(json_data.getString("ccode"));
                user.setCut(json_data.getString("cut"));
                user.setTotal(json_data.getString("total"));
                user.setFile(json_data.getString("file"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return users;
    }



    void addHeader(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        TextView add = new TextView(this);
        add.setText("Add");
        add.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        add.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        add.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(add,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText("Product code");

        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll);  // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView shapes = new TextView(this);
        shapes.setText("Shapes");
        shapes.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        shapes.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        shapes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(shapes,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView pair = new TextView(this);
        pair.setText("Shapes");
        pair.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        pair.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        pair.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(pair,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.




        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Users_fancystock> users) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Users_fancystock p = (Users_fancystock) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);




            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("Add to Basket");
            // btn.setTextSize();
            btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
            // btn.setTag(mLinks.get(index));
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            params.width=200;
            params.height=60;
            // btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));
            Ll.addView(btn,params);

            tr.addView((View)Ll);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getproduct_code());
            label.setId(p.getId());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            ////label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
             Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
             params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            TextView place = new TextView(this);
            place.setText(p.getShapes());
            place.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            place.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            //  place.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(place,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getpair());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            ////label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.



            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //  startActivity(f1);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your addData() function you must set the tag value with that button and this tag value you must set the i integer, and in onclick first you get tag and parse to integer and then get that index value from arraylist    ArrayList in which you already populate record from JSON. you will get object of fancystock from that index and that object contain record of you selected row.

tell me if you understand this and solve this problem :)

Updated//*********************************************************//

```
    ArrayList<Integer> users=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for(int i=0;i<users.size();i++){
       Button b=new Button(this);
       b.setTag(i);

   }
```

in onClickListner

```
    int i=(Integer)b.getTag();
    Users_fancystock rowRecord= users,get(i);
```

now this rowrecord will contain all values of row of your desired one

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your answers. Can you please give me some examples.